# Use shared realm or several STS tokens

Tags: security, saml, adfs, saml-2.0

Currently we are developing (at least) two different applications which will use an STS token for access control. The application are a part of the same SOA system and will always co-exist in.

App1 is secured by claimset1 and app2 is secured by claimset2.

Since STS tokens are requested for a certain realm, we have the choice to either

1. Merge claimset1&2 and use the same realm for both applications
2. Merge claimset1&2 and make app2 trust tokens issued for the app1 realm
3. Make app1 request a token for accessing app2 (using on-behalf-of)

To me the option 1 is most appealing, since we only need to use one single token. Aside from the STS configuration, can you please help me if there are any other considerations.

Thank you for your time. David

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends. If App1 needs to make calls to App2 on behalf of the user calling App1, you should go for option 3.

If App1 and App2 are completely independent, you should request a separate token for each app in order to prevent users from using a token they acquired for app1 to access resources in app2 (token forwarding).

Using the same realm for both applications I would only recommend if they are not really separate applications. If it's possible down the line, you need to add claims for app1 that app2 should not have access to (like sensitive info), it's no longer possible to distinguish the apps.

Comment: Thank you very much for input. The system always contains App2,

Comment: Yes, App1 always calls app2 "on-behalf-of". Thing is that these apps are part of the same system (even though the system CAN do without app1).  Thank you very much for input, pointing out that claims can trickle down was insightful.

Comment: You're welcome. No need for thanks. On SO you up vote a useful answer.